# Sometime growthbook's hook useFeature().source returning "defaultValue" as value

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, server-side-rendering, growthbook

hi i am using A/B testing with growthbook
i added a feature `stroke-care_page`

[image]

inside this feature i added two Experiment rule
with 50%-50% coverage
[image]

**In Code**
in `_app.js`

```
const growthbook = new GrowthBook({
  enableDevMode: true,
  trackingCallback: (experiment, result) => {
    console.log(" ~ file: _app.js ~ experiment", experiment)
    console.log(" ~ file: _app.js ~ result", result)
  },
});

useEffect(()=>{
fetchData()
},[])

const fetchData = async () => {
  const machine_id = getMachineId()
    fetch(FEATURES_ENDPOINT)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        growthbook.setFeatures(json.features);
      });

    growthbook.setAttributes({
      id: "user",
      loggedIn: true,
      deviceId: machine_id,
      employee: true,
      company: "ABC",
      browser: navigator.userAgent
    });
}
```

in `page.js`

growthbook's hook useFeature() hook to get value of a feature

```
const feature = useFeature("stroke-care_page");

useEffect(() => { 
 if (feature.source === "experiment") 
 { 
  setGrowthbookContent(feature.value)           
 } 
}, [feature.source])
```

but sometime `feature.source` returnning `defaultValue`

its should return `experiment` always

and i try to log `conosle.log(feature)` its value this sometime

[image]

**expected value **
sometime is work fine

[image]

i dont know why growthbook work like this?

Comment: Not sure what the question is)
And it's not clear what is the purpose of the checking feature.source at all.
And this source-changing behavior feels expected, because it really uses default values before Growthbook loaded the features\experiments.

Comment: hi i am using A/B testing with growthbook and adding a feature with 2 experiments and it will be return one feature base on id but its is not retuning any experiment value...

Comment: @Vishnu This is really not enough to reproduce the issue. Please create a [mcve].